# How to split a node app into different processes

Tags: node.js, supervisord

I am building a node application quite complexe, and i recently made the choice to use rabbitmq in order to write clean independant modules communicating with messages.

After implementing it, it appears very clear that my app is splitted into 3 independants parts that i could name:

1. "Emit" (do actions and emit what happens with rabbitmq): should still a single process because it keeps important datas in memory (unless datas could be shared between processes).
2. "Treat" (receive actions from Emit and treat/update the data): could run on different processes
3. "Display" (answer the HTTP requests with the fresh updated data): could run on different processes

Currently, everything works in one node application/process and it works great, but since these third parts are very independant, i would like to go further in the optimization by spliting it into 3 node apps/processes

The thing is, i am "only" a developer, and i really don't master this area, so i am quite afraid to "destroy everything" !

It comes with a lot a questions, like: How could i write functional tests ?
If i want to test "Emit send an event, then Treat works on it, then Dislpay is able to answer it". It means that the Emit and Treat node apps have to be run before i can run the test...

So this is a large subject, but to resume, my questions could be:

1. Is it a good idea to split a node app into different ones when they do different things in parallel, but still linked with events?
2. Are there best practices or tools for that?
3. Are there ways to develop your app in one "project", and split it into different processes in production (following specific conditions that some hypothetical tools could require) ?

As you have probably notice, these subjects are very vague to me, so every clarification will be really appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest that a coding project should be made no more complicated than it needs to be in order to meet your goals or the corollary that you should use the simplest construct available to meet your goals while achieving clear, robust and maintainable code.  So, unless you have a compelling reason to split your code into three apps now or in the expected future, I'm not sure why you would take on that complication.  Three apps will likely be more complicated than one.

Comment: As for the testing, you will want to design each app to be separately testable by itself so your tests can independently provide sample inputs and evaluate the outputs.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes i have no problem for unit test, juste for global functionnal tests, but it is not the most important.
i want to split the app for the significant performances i could have, it would be a good way to split the CPU consumption by 3 different processes that could be run on different machines.